# Memory jumping with jqGrid refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, internet-explorer-8

I have a jqGrid (v4.5.2) that is populated from local data.  Whenever I try to unload the grid and repopulate it with new data, using the `buildGrid()` function below, the memory in IE8 jumps.  After doing this about 15x, the memory has increases from ~80,000K to ~350,000K.  My use case calls for this grid to be refreshed > 150x without a browser refresh.

It's a pretty simple grid.  Here is my function to build it:

```
<table id="lpInfoGrid"><tr><td/></tr></table>
<div id="lpInfoGridPager"></div>

var jqGridObj;
function buildGrid(lot) {

    if (jqGridObj) {
        jqGridObj.jqGrid('GridUnload');
        jqGridObj = null;       
    }

    jqGridObj = $("#lpInfoGrid").jqGrid({
        data: localData[lot].Info,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: [...],
        colModel: [...],
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        pager: '#lpInfoGridPager'   
    });

}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I try to clear out and refresh the grid?

Comment: Hmmm...  how many rows do you have in your grid? Grasping at straws a bit, but are they tied to the rest of the page somehow, so as to prevent them from being garbage collected properly?

Comment: There are only 1-2K records.  They're collections of objects in `localData[lot]`. Basically my users scroll through these objects and when they get to a new one, I refresh the grid.  If I comment out the grid, the memory stays pretty constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have better luck using the `reloadGrid` function.  Since the other params are the same:

```
var jqGridObj = null;
function buildGrid(lot) {

    if (jqGridObj != null) {
        $('#lpInfoGrid').setGridParam({
            data: localData[lot].Info,
            datatype: 'local'            
        }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        return true;
    }

    jqGridObj = $('#lpInfoGrid').jqGrid({
        data: localData[lot].Info,
        datatype: 'local',
        colNames: [...],
        colModel: [...],
        viewrecords: true,        
        gridview: true,
        pager: '#lpInfoGridPager'
    });

}
```

This helps keep the memory under control.  I'll see if I run into any other isses downstream.